# Difference between IBM and Google Quantum Circuit?

Tags: experimental-realization

I am wondering what the internal differences between IBM and Google quantum circuits are.

They look so different. Google team seems to design their circuit in a fully-connected manner, while the chips from IBM are not so. What are the reasons for that? Is that the reason why Google cannot put their chip online but IBM can?

Best.

Comment: Google's chip is online: https://quantumai.google/quantum-computing-service. You need to apply for access.